# Differentiability of $f(x,y)=x^2\log|xy|$ at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have the function $f(x,y)$ which is null over axis and $$f(x,y)=x^2\log|xy|$$ 
otherwise.

The function is continuous in the origin because $$0\le|f(x,y)|\le x^2|xy|\rightarrow 0\quad\text{for}\quad(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0).$$

For the differentiability can I use theorem of gradient?

Comment: Your estimate on $|f|$ is wrong because $\log |xy|$ can blow up.

Comment: seems you assume $|\ln t|\leq |t|$ for all $t$. This is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You are wrong, the function $f$ is NOT continuous at the origin.

Consider the curve $$(0,1)\ni t \to(x(t),y(t))= (t,\exp(-1/t^2)).$$
Then $x(t)>0$, $y(t)>0$ for $t\in(0,1)$, $\lim_{t\to 0}x(t)=\lim_{t\to 0} y(t)=0$ and 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}f(x(t), y(t))= \lim_{t\to 0^+} t^2\log|t\exp(-1/t^2)|=
\lim_{t\to 0^+} \left(t^2\log(t)-1\right)=-1\not=0=f(0,0).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to find out the limit

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f'_x(0,0)x-f'_y(0,0)y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

Comment: I have this
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2log|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

Comment: See $x \leq \sqrt (x^{2}+y^{2})$ and $y \leq \sqrt (x^{2}+y^{2})$ then $\log \vert xy \vert < \log (x^{2}+y^{2})$. I think now you got the answer.

Comment: so f is differentiable in the origin

Comment: @1256 $f$ is NOT continuous at the origin!!